# Convert string to hebrew

Tags: php, string, encoding, decoding

I have the following string:

> ×”×ž×¨×›×– ×”×‘×™× ×ª×—×•×ž×™ ×”×¨×¦×œ×™×”

How can I convert it to Hebrew using PHP? I try `ut8_decode` and `utf8_encode` and it doesn't work.

Comment: what do you think it currently is ? what's the source of the string?

Comment: Please show your code and markup, and preferably an example page with source code.

Answer (score 4):

You have a UTF-8 byte sequence that you are displaying using the Windows code page 1252 (Western European) encoding instead of UTF-8.

Ensure that your output page is served as UTF-8 using a `Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8` header and/or `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>` tag, and the sequence should be interpreted correct by the browser as UTF-8, giving ‘המרכז הבינתחומי הרצליה’.